# 2 tiered SQL statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am quite new to SQL so bear with me for a moment... I wish to select email from a table called task allocation where task ID= (all the task ID in another table which has a value of say maybe X in a column called project ID. I wish to only select unique emails. May I know if this is possible in a single sql statement? Thanks a lot for any help rendered!

Comment: Yes, this is very possible. What have you tried, though?

Comment: what does your schema(format of your tables) look like

Comment: SQL although important is not central to MS Access front-end design. I believe this is a valid design question, rather than database question. Furthermore, I do not believe that you could easily google such a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the query design window to gradually build up an sql statement. For example, you can build the following:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TaskID From SomeTable WHERE ColX="X"
```

You can get the DISTINCT keyword by right-clicking, choosing properties and selecting Unique Values.

You can also build:

```
 SELECT Email From ATable As A
 INNER JOIN SomeTable As B
 ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID
```

Now Substitute:

```
 SELECT Email From ATable As A
 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TaskID From SomeTable WHERE ColX="X") As B
 ON a.TaskID = b.TaskID
```